# Reestablish the removed portlet from WebSphere Portal

Tags: java, deployment, portlet, websphere-portal

There is an ear deployed into WebSphere WAS. It contains 3 portlets. I imported XML descriptor for this app to the WebSphere Portal and put the portlets on portal pages. It was working.

Unfortunately I removed one of the portlets from web modules in portal administration. Because of this portlet was removed from all pages also. I can't find the portlet in portlets list, so I can't put it to the pages again.

How can I reestablish the removed portlet to portal without uninstalling and deploying whole ear application to application server again.

I tried to import portlet XML to portal again. But it didn't help

**UPDATE**

here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="PortalConfig_7.0.0.xsd" type="update" create-oids="true">
<portal action="locate">
    <web-app action="update" active="true" domain="rel" predeployed="true" removable="true" uid="kz.edu.nu.world.roomreservation.RoomReservationPortlet.4207700365webmod">
    <url>file://localhost/opt/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile/installedApps/Cell01/RoomReservationEAR.ear/RoomReservation.war</url>
        <context-root>/.RoomReservation</context-root>
        <display-name>.RoomReservation</display-name>
       <portlet-app action="update" active="true" defaultlocale="en" domain="rel" name="kz.edu.nu.world.roomreservation.RoomReservationPortlet.4207700365" uid="kz.edu.nu.world.roomreservation.RoomReservationPortlet.4207700365">
            <portlet action="update" active="true" defaultlocale="en" domain="rel" name="RoomReservation" provided="false">
                <localedata locale="en">
                    <title>RoomReservation</title>
                </localedata>
        <localedata locale="ru">
                    <title>RoomReservation</title>
                </localedata>
        <localedata locale="kk">
                    <title>RoomReservation</title>
                </localedata>
            </portlet>
        </portlet-app>
    </web-app>
</portal>
</request>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but you will need to update the ear.  I don't think you have to uninstall the ear, just update it and import xml again.

Comment: I updated ear by console. But it doesn't work. When I try to restart ear application the server says that portlet is deployed in the application server but not registered with portal

Comment: And you imported the xml again?  Can you post the xml?